# Feature Extraction - How to ONLY Detect SIFT Feautures OUTSIDE Region of Interest?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, sift

I understand that it is possible to exclusively extract features INSIDE a ROI by providing a mask to the sift feature detector. I am wondering if it is possible to exclusively extract SIFT features OUTSIDE the ROI instead?

From my understanding, when you create a mask, you are filling the original image with zeros, with the size of original image

```
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
```

and then you must draw your selected ROI on the mask image, to specify the area you want the sift detector to focus on

```
cv2.rectangle(mask, (50,50), (150,150), (255), thickness = -1)
```

From here you could detect and draw the keypoints INSIDE the ROI of your image

```
kp = sift.detect(gray,mask) #passing mask here so sift only looks for keypoints within your ROI
```

I am trying to use this knowledge to only detect features outside my ROI, but have had no success. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Just create an ROI that is the inverse of your ROI, by maskInverse=255-mask

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did not realize inverseMask was possible. Can you please clarify what you mean by 255? This will help me understand the process of why this works better.

Comment: In your mask, the white pixels are value 255 and the black pixels are 0. So a mat of same size with every pixels initialized with value 255 minus your current mask will give a mask that has value 0 everywhere where your current mask was value 255 and has value 255 everywhere your current mask was value 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the mask like this

```
mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(mask, (50,50), (150,150), (0), thickness = -1)
```